# What am I missing from this jQuery Masonry implementation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tumblr, jquery-masonry

I've sifted through the plethora of Masonry posts here on stack, and view-sourced other tumblr blogs, but am unable to recognize what I am missing. Hopefully one of you can help.

The site in question is available <strike>**here**</strike> for visual reference (note: 1 or 2 fashion swimsuit photos - tame but potentially NSFW for some).

As you can see, the images are still not vertically stacking properly. Where have I gone wrong?

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #000;
    height: 400px;

}

#wrapper .posts {
    background: #ff9900;
    width: 950px;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper .entry {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
```

Masonry Script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/yflpwuf/SSOm2d3y2/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var $posts = $('.posts');

$posts.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $posts.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.entry',
    columnWidth: 300

  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [faq] about how to ask a good question.

Comment: Care to elaborate? "...practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." — have I not met this suggestion?

Comment: No, you haven't done many things. One, would be you have pasted your entire page here, but what you should have done is only post the relevant codes necessary to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, this is such a basic skeleton with so few lines of code, I would never have imagined it would get in the way. I'll make the adjustment.

Comment: Curated the code. What other "many things" am I missing?

Comment: Did some edits myself, rest is up to the community. For the many things, join [meta] and surf around.

Comment: Thank you Starx for your welcome, direction, and patience.

Comment: Thats a great attitude +1 from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Masonry script you provided here seems OK (the one in the link you provided is faulty). Try just moving it to the bottom of the document, right before the closing tag for 'body'

```
...</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/ jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/yflpwuf/SSOm2d3y2/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var $posts = $('.posts');

$posts.imagesLoaded( function(){
$posts.masonry({
itemSelector : '.entry',
columnWidth: 300

 });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried this, it did not change anything unfortunately. Every working masonry tumblr example I've explored has kept the script within the <head>, but I do understand that it is often beneficial to load scripts towards the bottom of the document. It seems the problem is beyond where the script is placed.

Comment: Ah ha! Tried leaving the script src definition within the head, while moving the script itself to the bottom of the document. Thank you! I believe this is otherwise bug free now.

Answer (score 3):

There is an `imagesLoaded` error because the function isn't defined.  Your jquery.masonry.min.js looks like it's missing the [imagesLoaded plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded).  Grab a copy of [this minified masonry source](http://masonry.desandro.com/jquery.masonry.min.js) instead which appears to have imagesLoaded and look at the [docs](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html)

Comment: I've tried using this new masonry source, but to no avail. I'll take another look through the docs, thank you.

Comment: Thank you again Dylan, my problem was aided by the advice of both bjnvnen and yourself.

Comment: Great! don't be afraid to upvote both of us if the info was useful

Comment: Need 2 more reputation to upvote - but I'll be sure to revisit this question.